# Set width of border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the red dotted border fit my row. At the moment the border is going out of the row, but I would like the line to be inside the row like this:

[image]

I am not quite sure if it is possible to control the width of a border?

```css
.sbp-products-row {
    border-bottom:1px dotted red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="sbp-item7">
      <div class="row sbp-products-row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
              <a href="#">
                  <img class="sbp-product-img" src="https://i.etsystatic.com/isla/aee233/24534674/isla_75x75.24534674_ozrbr80h.jpg">
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
              <h4><a class="sbp-product-title" href="#">Produkt</a></h4>
              <p>Produkt tekst</p>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `.sbp-products-row` is wider than `.sbp-item7`. You can verify this by outlining both elements to visibly see their widths with CSS `outline: 1px solid` on both of the elements.

I would try setting `.sbp-products-row` with `width: 100%;` so that it is 100% of the width of its parent.

It also looks like you don't want the red border line to touch the walls of the container (which is `.sbp-item7`, so I would also give `.sbp-item7` some padding - `padding: 10px;`.

For visible testing of the sizes of these elements (temporary):

```
.sbp-products-row, .sbp-item7 {
    outline: 1px solid;
}
```

These styles might work:

```
.sbp-products-row {
    padding: 10px;
}

.sbp-item7 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Another commenter suggested using negative margins, which you can try to do, but negative margins should never be your first plan of attack.